# What is the difference between offset and postion of a kinetic container

Tags: kineticjs

Kinetic.js allows you to set and get the position and the offset a kinetic container subclass (shape, group, layer, stage, etc).

Please explain what the difference is between the offset and position property. When should one be used vs the other.

Answer (score 4):

**Position** is usefull to set **where is your container** should be placed on parent container.

**Offset** is useful to set **where is the center** of you container.

By default when you are setting position of rectange (for example) you are setting top left point position.
So top left point is "center" of rectange. If you will use rotation, rectange will be rotated related it center.
Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/55Bxq/

```
      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 578,
        height: 200
      });
      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
      var rect1 = new Kinetic.Rect({
         x : 100,
         y : 100,
         width: 50,
         height: 50,
         fill: 'green',
         stroke: 'black'
      });
      layer.add(rect1);
    var rect2 = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x : 250,
        y : 125,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        offset : {x : 25, y : 25}
      });
      layer.add(rect2);
      stage.add(layer);

      var tween1 = new Kinetic.Tween({
          node : rect1,
          duration: 1,
          rotation: Math.PI * 2
      });
    var tween2 = new Kinetic.Tween({
          node : rect2,
          duration: 1,
          rotation: Math.PI * 2
      });

      // start tween after 2 seconds
      setTimeout(function() {
        tween1.play();
        tween2.play();
      }, 2000);
```